# VSCode CMake Configuration Fail on Windows10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

VSCode not configuring CMakeLists.txt file. It says `no folder is open`.

```
OS: Windows 10
VSCode version: 1.74.3
Cmake version: 3.23.1
```

Cmake, CMake Tools, C/C++ extensions are already installed.

Steps followed:

1. Create an empty folder.
2. Open in VSCode.
3. Ctrl + Shift + P > CMake: Quick Start

I am trying to setup OpenCV C++ on VSCode.

[image]

Comment: does this help ?? ...
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5296005/How-to-Open-Folder-Directly-in-Visual-Studio-Code

Comment: I cannot get it to work either, and I am pretty sure I have used it in the past. So I think it smells like they broke something in an update.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [vscode-cmake-tools@1.13.41 - Fix "No folder is open" error when running quick start.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/pull/2954), try downgrade version to 1.12.27

Comment: I downgraded it to 1.53.2 and is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I am a complete beginner in this stuff but i just had this issue and was able to solve it. I am not sure which one of the steps exactly helped me but here is everything i did that might have affected it:

1. Uninstalled and reinstalled CMake choosing "Add CMake to the system PATH for all users"
2. Installed Visual Studio 2022 c++ tool for windows
3. Restarted my pc
4. Added paths to opencv/build/x64/vc15/bin and lib and to the CMake's bin
5. Created a cmakelist.txt by hand and copied contents from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9HBM1m_EMU
6. Reinstalled CMake extensions and downloaded c/c++ compile run extension(even though i already have code runner installed)
7. With the DIY file crated in step 5 tried ctrl+shift+p and chose CMake configure and then CMake quick run(resulted in error saying that
   cmakelist exists already)
8. Removed handmade cmakelist and did configure->quick run again(and it worked!!!)
   Hope this helps